# How to make link as "domain.com/website.com" in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I redirected to domain.com/website, but it should redirect to domain.com/website.com. Using permalinks it shows as domain.com/website-com Is it possible to change the permalink.

Comment: for redirect domain.com/website you might be need to create folder with our site name in your server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create website directory in domain.com and configure site_url and home_url

So the website run with domain.com/website